# Sharepoint Correlation Error

Tags: 2010

I am getting correlation error for particular user when trying to access the site it keep loading too.

Regards,
Mohamed.

Comment: Check the SharePoint error logs on server

Comment: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS this log right?

Comment: Are you using SP-online or Sharepoint on Prem? (Like SP2013/2016)? The log path you are asking about is only for on prem Sharepoint

Comment: I am using sp2010

Comment: Download ULS Viewer from this url, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020, and run it on all servers to check if there is something related to the correlation id you get from the user.

Answer (score 0):

As this is SP online you cannot get details of the error on  your own (unless it is BCS related). You need to open ticket with MS support.

Ok in case of SP2010 get yourself ULS log viewer. Use it to find your correlation error this should put you on right path to troubleshoot. if you have specific error please open new question on forum.

Comment: No it  is sp2010

Comment: In the tags you have put Sharepoint-online, will correct it.

Comment: Oh ok. I am getting error for particular user.